# File UPLOAD error -> Trying access the php.ini file into the OPENSHIFT free application and get Permission Denied response

Tags: php, file-upload, permissions, openshift

I'm trying to save a file into the serverusing the statements below but it doesn't work! I heard I would need to access the php.ini file but it says I don't have permission... What should I do to solve it???

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_0']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$data['filename'])
```

But used this way earlier and seems it didn't work too...

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_0']['tmp_name'], '$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'uploads/'.$data['filename']
```

In case there is a certain directory where I I can have the write permission, please tell me(would help me a lot too).

Comment: Thanks for the editing @wogsland. I was in a hurry and forgot to format it properly

Comment: Just found the answer... First of all it's about directory permission...  In openshift it's wise to use $_ENV['OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'] as the root.... And beside that I haven't created the "/uploads/" folder... I thought the move_uploaded_file() function would create it if it was not yet, but I was wrong.. Just used mkdir command and voulá

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer... First of all it's about directory permission... In openshift it's wise to use $_ENV['OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'] as the root.... And beside that I haven't created the "/uploads/" folder... I thought the move_uploaded_file() function would create it if it was not yet, but I was wrong.. Just used mkdir command and voulá